# Submit multiple products via Woocommerce order API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to use the [Woocommmerce order API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#order-properties).

I can submit this successfully as per the object below.

```js
        data = {
        "order": {
            "payment_details": {
                "method_id": "bacs",
                "method_title": "direct bank",
                "paid": false,
                "status": "pending"
            },
            "billing_address": {
                "first_name": $scope.f_name,
                "last_name": $scope.l_name,
                "address_1": $scope.address1,
                "address_2": $scope.address2,
                "city": $scope.city,
                "state": $scope.state,
                "postcode": $scope.postcode,
                "country": $scope.country,
                "email": $scope.email,
                "phone": $scope.phone
            },
            "shipping_address": {
                "first_name": $scope.f_name,
                "last_name": $scope.l_name,
                "address_1": $scope.address1,
                "address_2": $scope.address2,
                "city": $scope.city,
                "state": $scope.state,
                "postcode": $scope.postcode,
                "country": $scope.country
            },
            "customer_id": $scope.user_id,
            "line_items": [{
                "product_id": $scope.ids,
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        }
```

However my issue comes in when I to to submit multiple products. I am not sure how to do this.

I know that I can just repeat the (`"product_id": $scope.ids, "quantity": 1`) parameters but I don't know how many products the user will submit so this won't be effective. My thinking is that I need to somehow concatenate all the product id's and push to the object. Please assist?

I have since tried to run a for loop to get all the product id's and append it to a variable called obj which is then added to the object but still no luck.

```js
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.basketProducts.length; i++) {
    obj = "product_id:" + $scope.basketProducts[i].id + ",quantity:1";
    console.log(obj);
    }

    "line_items": [{
                    obj
                  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function to concatenate the results of both arrays.

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

Comment: thanks for your response however I don't know how many products there will be, needs to be dynamic and follow the api's structure